# trying to get first child elements in d3.js at first load time

Tags: jquery, d3.js, nodes

I am getting data from json

```
{
    "name": "abcd", "size": 150000,
        "children": [

                    {
                    "name": "Modules", "size": 100000,
                    "children": [
                    {"name": "Audio Library", "size": 100000, "info": "hello", "image": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/web2tools-production/images/199/Google_logo.PNG"},
                    {"name": "CommentBox", "size": 100000, "info": "hi" },
                    {"name": "Localization", "size": 100000, "info": "hi there"} 
                                ]
                                },
                                {
                                 "name": "Features", "size": 100000,
                    "children": [
                    {"name": "Rapid Development", "size": 100000, "info": "hello", "image": "http://s3.amazonaws.com/web2tools-production/images/199/Google_logo.PNG"},
                    {"name": "User friendly interface", "size": 100000, "info": "hi" },
                    {"name": "Highly Customizable", "size": 100000, "info": "hi there"},
                     {"name": "Full control", "size": 100000, "info": "hi" },
                    {"name": "Open Source", "size": 100000, "info": "hi there"} 
                                ]
                    } 


                    ]       

}
```

Now i am trying to get "Collapsible Force Layout" effect using d3.js
as http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130

But I want to load only first child element at first load time .

In my case

- First root----->abcd First child---->Modules Second Child--->Features

I am using flatten function to get all nodes from json

```
function flatten(root) {
            var nodes = [], i = 0;

            function recurse(node) {
                if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
                if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
                nodes.push(node);
            }
            recurse(root);
            return nodes;
        }
```

Now,how can i get first child elements from this function.
I am just new to d3.js and little bit confused about this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use recursion :

```
var node=[]
root.children.forEach(function(d){ node.push(d.children[0])})
console.log(node)
```

jsfiddl : http://jsfiddle.net/nCLX9/

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the top level child elements as a special case, couldn't you just access `root.children`?

If you want to return any arbitrary level you could add a level restriction to the recurse function.  Something like (untested):

```
function flatten(root, level) {
    level = level !== undefined ? level : 1;
    var nodes = [], i = 0;

    function recurse(node, currentLevel) {
        currentLevel !== undefined ? currentLevel : 1;
        if (node.children && currentLevel < level) {
            node.children.forEach(function(child) {
                recurse(child, currentLevel+1);
            });
        }
        if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
        nodes.push(node);
    }
    recurse(root);
    return nodes;
}
```